# Xcode 4 most useful shortcut keys

Tags: xcode

I have just had the chance to use Xcode 4, it seems to have a complex interface, I would like to know about the most useful shortcut keys so that I can take full advantage of it. Someone is willing to share?

Comment: This is available in Xcode 3, but if you use 3-fingers to scroll up or down on the trackpad it will toggle between the .h and .m of the file you're viewing.  Alternatively, you can use command-up arrow and command-down arrow.

Comment: In Preferences > Key Bindings you can find a list of all of them, with a search field.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here you can find a nice overview of Xcode 4 shortcuts that you can print out:

http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2011/03/xcode-4-keyboard-shortcuts-now.html

Comment: That's gotta be the definitive guide. :)

Comment: excellent documentation! thanks!

Comment: What happened to the "Find Selected Text in API" shortcut? I miss that one! I believe it used to be Command + Option + Double-Click

Comment: @jocull option+click opens quickhelp for the clicked word in a popup, from there you can easily jump to the full documentation

Comment: Also, Ctrl+Shift+O (letter) opens "Quick Open" where you can type the name of a file, class, variable or other text and open the file that contains it

Comment: @HariKaramSingh you mean Shift+Cmd+O - this is also mentioned in the shortcut sheet

Comment: Oh yes, thank you.  Still have some old PC habits lingering in my brain ;)

Answer (score 57):

Here are a few commands I use to open / close different areas of the screen

[image]

Comment: But how do you actually switch the cursor to the assistant editor? You'd still need the mouse yeah?

Comment: Yes, the mouse is probably the easiest option.  Although you could use cmd-j, down arrow, enter.

Comment: woah, thanks! Always wished for a way to quickly switch between the two.

Comment: I'm an Eclipse user, and switching between project navigator and editor is one of the most common actions. Isn't really a shorter shortcut? PD: really useful image, Robert, thanks!

Comment: @juanignaciosl there are Move Focus to Next/Previous items in the Navigate menu. In Preferences you can assign them to whatever key you're used to from eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Command + Control + Up alternates between .m and .h files.