# Xcode 4: Keyboard shortcut for switching Assistant Editor to Tracking (Automatic) mode?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I like using the Assistant Editor in Xcode 4. I frequently Option-Click files to open them in the Assistant Editor, or use Open Quickly (Command-Shift-O), and hold the option key when selecting a file to open it in the Assistant Editor.

Both of these actions switch the Assistant Editor to Manual mode. Is there a keyboard shortcut to switch the Assistant Editor back to Tracking mode (also called Automatic)? In tracking mode it automatically shows the counterpart, e.g. the corresponding header/implementation file for the file in your main editor. know I can select Automatic mode it with the mouse on the Assistant Editor Jump bar, but I really want a keyboard shortcut to do this.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In the View -> Assistant Editor menu, there's an item called "Reset Editor". The default keyboard shortcut is Cmd-Opt-Shift-Z. It resets the Assistant View to show Counterparts.

I don't know if it's new in Xcode 4.1, but it should be a little easier than AppleScripting.

Alternatively, you could create a behavior to reset the editor how you'd like and bind it to a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Genius keyboard shortcut. I should map it to, I dunno, spacebar.

Answer (score 102):

I made this to help answer [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263703/xcode-4-most-useful-shortcut-keys/8310562#8310562)... Does it help?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do it, but not with just a single "standard" keyboard shortcut. Assuming that you have just Option-Clicked on a file and opened it in the Assistant Editor, you would do the following steps to switch to "Counterparts" mode in the Assistant Editor:

1. If your focus is not on the Assistant Editor, press Command-Option-.
   until you are on it.
2. Once focus is on the Assistant Editor, press Control-4 to drop down
   the Assistant Editor menu.
3. "Manual" will be selected so Press DownArrow once to select
   "Counterparts" and press Enter to switch to the counterpart of the
   file in the main editor.

If this is too many keystrokes, you can put the keys for steps 2 & 3 in an AppleScript script and bind it to a key.

Comment: Thanks. In lieu of a real keyboard shortcut, that's a pretty good alternative. Two notes for others - I had to disable the Ctrl 1-4 keyboard shortcut for changing Mac OS X Spaces. Also, Command-J for visual way to select your editor with the keyboard is a useful alternative to Command-Option-.