# Xcode 4 shortcut for swapping focus between editor and assistant editor

Tags: xcode, xcode4

In Xcode, I am big fan of the assitant editor that shows me the corresponding .h or .m for the file that I am editing.

Is there a shortcut that allows me to swap focus between this two windows? I frequently switch between the two and using the mouse every time is annoying.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

@Oneiros: Not quite what the OP was asking for..

I don't know of a 'short' shortcut but there's `Cmd-J` showing a popup where you can choose what to focus.

Comment: Cool, thanks. The correct answer wasn't exactly what I was looking for but it was close enough.

Comment: You might also want to check out `Cmd-Opt-.` and `Cmd-Opt-Shift-.` for the '*Move Focus to ..*' shortcuts -  
takes a while to discover all those shortcuts ;-)

Comment: In Xcode 8 you can use the new shortcut `Ctrl-\`` - Move Focus to Next Editor. See my answer below.

Answer (score 101):

**New answer:**

*Move Focus To Editor* — <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> followed by <kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>return</kbd>

This goes nicely together with <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> which is *Reveal in Project Navigator*.

**Old answer:**

Use <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> keyboard shortcut.

It can be remapped in *Preferences* - *Keyboard Bindings* - *Move Focus To Next Area*.

*Edit: Removed XVim recommendation.*

Comment: I think XVim is the most efficient way.

Comment: If you use the side of your thumb to press both Cmd and Opt, it's not bad at all.

Comment: Ctrl+w followed by w will also switch focus in XVim.

Comment: This (`opt+cmd+\``) key combination is what I was looking for for a long time. Thank you Rudolf! Still works in Xcode 7.3 and 2016.

Comment: I am using XVim in Xcode 8. "control + w followed by w or hjkl" seems broken. Any clue?

Answer (score 85):

I made this to help answer [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263703/xcode-4-most-useful-shortcut-keys/8310562#8310562)... Does it help?

[image: XCode shortcuts]

Comment: Two very important omissions: _shift + cmd + j_ to focus _Project Navigator_ and _cmd + j_ to focus (any) editor. That's files and their content. Bread and butter. :)

Comment: It looks like **cmd + alt + j** shortcut does not work for me. I guess I accidentally changed this shortcut. Could you tell how does this feature call in Key Bindings list?

Comment: I've finally found that shortcut. **cmd+ctrl+j** - enjoy!

Comment: This is incredibly helpful. I've saved this image. Many thanks Robert!

Comment: Saved !! Tch. I have this as my wallpaper now.

Answer (score 25):

## Xcode 8+

This is the easiest option:

<kbd>^</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> - Move Focus to Next Editor

When using multiple assistant editors, <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>^</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> moves focus to **previous** editor.

## Xcode 4+

<kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> - Move Focus to **Next** Area
<kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> - Move Focus to **Previous** Area

Using this option you can switch between Project Navigator (left pane), Primary Editor, Assistant Editors, Utility Area (right pane), Debug Area, etc.

---

<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> - Move Focus to Editor...

Using this option you can choose where to move the focus using graphical navigation chooser.

Answer (score 12):

For Xcode 4.4:
Use Cmd+Option+` (left to number 1) to Move Focus to Next Area, and use Cmd+Option+Shift+` to Move Focus to Previous Area

For Xcode 4.3:
If you only have the Editor and Assistant open, use Cmd+Option+. to switch between them (Navigator>Move Focus to next area)

Answer (score 10):

Also, if you want to open a different file in the right pane, like the .xib or any other, press

<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd><kbd>shift ⇧</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>

The *open quickly* window will appear, search the file, use capital letters to filter through camel case notation, then press

<kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd><kbd>enter ↵</kbd>

The file will be opened in the assistant window

Answer (score 4):

Switching between .h and .m:
<kbd>Control ^</kbd><kbd>Command ⌘</kbd><kbd>Up Arrow ↑</kbd>

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. I had a lot of trouble finding this hint. Perhaps I didn't make a good job of structuring my query. I didn't want to just change focus, but wanted to swap the contents of the two panes. This tip does exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

Assume you have Standart(`S`) and Assistance(`A`) editor opened and you want swap them.

[image]

1) Double tap with holded <kbd>Alt</kbd> to line in navigation bar of `S` editor with file name (look screenshot). This file will open in `A` editor.
2) In `A` editor tap `Go Back` and do `1`. File from `A` editor will be opened in `S` editor.
3) In `A` editor tap `Go Forward`.

DONE!